# HTTP GET Request for Tweets with Passport.js and Express.js

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, express, passport-twitter

I'm new to Express.js, Node.js, and Passport.js. I'm trying to develop an application where a user signs in with their Twitter account and then they can see their Mentions (Tweets in which other Twitter users have mentioned the logged in user's Twitter username). I came across Passport.js, and I have been able to use it successfully allow a user to sign in with their Twitter account.

However, I am not sure how to format a server-side HTTP GET request for the Twitter Mentions. I've reviewed the Twitter API numerous times at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/mentions, but since I'm unfamiliar with the Node/Express/Passport platform, I'm not sure how to perform this request server-side to return JSON-formatted Mentions. The application is set up to be read-only, as it only needs to be able to see relevant Tweets with the associated user.

The front-end is based on EJS. Below is what code I have that may be relevant. Thank you very much for your help.

-joshingmachine

/app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , http = require('http')
  , util = require('util')
  , path = require('path')
  , TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;

var TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "theConsumerKeyForMyApp";
var TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "theConsumerSecretForMyApp";

var users = [];

// Passport session setup.
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  var user = users[id];
  done(null, user);
});


// Use the TwitterStrategy within Passport.
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    //console.log(token);
    //console.log(tokenSecret);
    //console.log(profile);
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
      var user = users[profile.id] || (users[profile.id] = profile);
      done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

var app = express();

// configure Express
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret:'secret'}));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', { user: req.user });
});

// GET /auth/twitter
app.get('/auth/twitter',
  passport.authenticate('twitter'),
  function(req, res){
    // The request will be redirected to Twitter for authentication, so this
    // function will not be called.
  });

// GET /auth/twitter/callback
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

// Create server
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

// Simple route middleware to ensure user is authenticated.
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login');
}

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.send(404, '404 Not Found');
});
```

/routes/index.js

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Install the module:

```
npm install oauth
```

Then use this code to create your GET request(replace the variables as needed).

```
var oauth = new OAuth.OAuth(
  'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
  'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
  'your application consumer key',
  'your application secret',
  '1.0A',
  null,
  'HMAC-SHA1'
);
oauth.get(
  'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=23424977',
  'your user toke for this app', //test user token
  'your user secret for this app', //test user secret            
  function (e, data, res){
    if (e) console.error(e);        
    console.log(require('util').inspect(data));
    done();      
  });
```

And reference here if you need more info. Good luck! 
https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth

Answer (score 0):

I created something similar to what you're trying to do.  Since you've signed in succesfully, I'm assuming that you're able to get the access token and secret.  Once you have those, use an external library like [mtwitter](https://github.com/passcod/mtwitter).  I made the call like this (editing out the parts where i get the tokens from my db):

```
app.get('/twitter/userMentions', function (req, res) {
    var twit = new mtwitter({
        consumer_key: consumerKey,
        consumer_secret: consumerSecret,
        access_token_key: token,
        access_token_secret: secret
    });

    twit.get("/statuses/mentions_timeline", { "include_entities": false },
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.write(err.toString());
            }
            else res.write(JSON.stringify(data));

            res.end('\n');
        });
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for **Request** node module !!

https://npmjs.org/package/request